# Ограничение выбора в календарной форме

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Можно ли в календарной форме datepicker ограничить возможность выбора только определенным днем недели? Средствами из коробки, так сказать. В документации искала, не нашла. Но, возможно, я что-то упустила.

Comment: [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: @Dmitry, да, это оно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опция [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

Функция принимает в качестве параметра дату [`Date`](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime) и должна вернуть массив:

`[0]`: `true` или `false`, определяет доступна ли дата для выбора
`[1]`: имя CSS класса добавляемое для ячейки даты, `""` для отображения по умолчанию
`[2]`: подсказка (tooltip) при наведении указателя на дату

Функция вызывается для каждого дня в календаре до того, как он будет отображен.

---

Чтобы решить задачу, нужно в обработчике `beforeShowDay` для даты определить день недели с помощью функции `.getDay()`, которая вернет номер дня недели от 0 (воскресенье) до 6 (суббота).

Код примера:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [date.getDay() === 1]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```